# Removing popups defined in other event listener functions

Tags: javascript, popup, mapbox-gl

My event listener function opens `i` number of popups based on the length of variable `codedCities`, which dynamically changes.  This function works perfectly well but the problem is removing the popups.   On `'mouseout'` I would like all of popups that opened in `'mouseover'` to close.

```
item.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {

          for (var i in codedCities) {

 var  popupB = new mapboxgl.Popup({
                offset: [0, -10],
                closeButton: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                anchor: 'top-left'
            });

              popupB.setLngLat(codedCities[i].geometry.coordinates)
              .setHTML('<div>' + codedCities[i].properties.city + '</div>')
              .addTo(map);

        }

  });
```

With Mapbox GL, a new `mapboxgl.Popup` instance much be created for each feature, which means that the same number of popups have to be removed.  So far, I've tried:

```
    item.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {

      if (popupB){
          popupB.remove();
        } else {
          console.log("no more popups!")
        }
    });
```

But this did not work because `popupB` is a local variable defined in a previous function.   Then I tried defining `popupB` as a global variable in the previous function with `window.popupB` but then only *one* instance popupB is removed, not all of them.  Then I tried adding a number [i] to the popup variable name and looping through all the popups with
`window["popup" + i] = new mapboxgl.Popup`

```
        item.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {

        var step;
        for (step = 0; step < codedCities.length ; step++) {    
        window["popup" + step].remove();

          }
      });
```

But this displays nothing at all.  I am wondering if there is a known workaround to this problem.

How can I define and create popups in the `mouseover` function and then remove those exact same popups in the `mouseout` function?

Is there a way to include what I want in `mouseout`  *within*  the `mouseover` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a common css class on the popups and on **mouseout** , just target object with that css class and close them.

Comment: I already have a       `.mapboxgl-popup {

      max-width: 150px;
      max-height: 250px;
      font: 12px/20px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      border-radius: 5px;

      }` class for another type of popup in the application , how can I define another mapbox-gl popup class for this case?  Could you give an example?

Comment: As there is no simple attribute to add class on mapbox popup, you can just do the the following on setHtml

 popupB.setLngLat(codedCities[i].geometry.coordinates)
              .setHTML('<div class="coded-cities-popup">' + codedCities[i].properties.city + '</div>')
              .addTo(map);
    
Then on mouseout , use the following query to find out the popups,
 
if($('.mapboxgl-popup').find('p.coded-cities-popup').length != 0){
    //close the popups and stuff
     }

Comment: Thanks! What is the `p.` in `p.coded-cities-popup`?